# How to avoid control right to left property be affected by container

Tags: c#, vb.net, properties, controls

How can I force a control right to left and font property (and other properties if they are affected) in C# or Vb.net not to be affected by their containers?

For example when I put a Textbox into a panel which it's font is "Font A", Textbox font property font becomes "Font A". How can I avoid this?

Comment: Set a specific font on the textbox.

Comment: what about right to left property? what if I'm designing an inherited control?

Comment: Set the right-to-left property explicitly as well. If not explicitly set, controls will inherit some property values (by being ambient properties). That's just the way it is. If you're designing your own control, you can use the [DefaultValue] attribute on design properties to override default values. I think.

Comment: You really should be using default system settings for fonts and such if you can, however, to let the user choose how they want their experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override property (so its value is not default for that control type and not taken from parent somehow) you can do following

```
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public new bool AutoSize
    {
        get { return base.AutoSize; }
        set { base.AutoSize = value; }
    }

    public MyLabel()
    {
        AutoSize = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does MyLabel do? when it is called?